# How to select rows and nearby rows with specific conditions

Tags: sql

I have a table (Trans) of values like

```
OrderID (unique) | CustID  | OrderDate| TimeSinceLast|                  
------------------------------------------------------
    123a         | A01     | 20.06.18 |    20        |
    123y         | B05     | 20.06.18 |    31        |
    113k         | A01     | 18.05.18 |    NULL      | <------- need this
    168x         | C01     | 17.04.18 |    8         |
    999y         | B05     | 15.04.18 |    NULL      | <------- need this
    188k         | A01     | 15.04.18 |   123        |
    678a         | B05     | 16.03.18 |    45        |
```

What I need is to select the rows where TimeSinceLast is null, as well as a row preceding and following where TimeSinceLast is not null, grouped by custID

I'd need my final table to look like:

```
    OrderID (unique) | CustID  | OrderDate| TimeSinceLast|                  
    ------------------------------------------------------
        123a         | A01     | 20.06.18 |    20        | 
        113k         | A01     | 18.05.18 |    NULL      | 
        188k         | A01     | 15.04.18 |   123        | 
        123y         | B05     | 20.06.18 |    31        |
        999y         | B05     | 15.04.18 |    NULL      |
        678a         | B05     | 16.03.18 |    45        |
```

The main problem is that TimeSinceLast is not reliable and for whatsoever reason does not calculate well the days since last order, so I cannot use it in a query for preceding or following row. 
I have tried to look for codes and found something like this on this forum

```
 with dt as
       (select distinct custID, OrderID,
        max (case when timeSinceLast is null then OrderID end)
        over(partition by custID order by OrderDate
             rows between 1 preceding and 1 following) as NullID
        from Trans)
    select *
    from dt
    where request_id between NullID -1 and NullID+1
```

But does not work well for my purposes. Also it looks like max function cannot work with missing values.

Many thanks

Comment: Please define what do you mean by "preceding" and "following" rows. In a RDBMS rows do not have predefined ordering; you define the ordering using the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Voting to close since the question is unclear.

Comment: Wait! I'm trying to edit my question. Just getting my head around it.

Comment: Your code references columns that are not in the sample data, such as `AddedDate` and `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lead()` and `lag()`.

> What I need is to select the rows where TimeSinceLast is null, as well as a row preceding and following where TimeSinceLast is not null.

First, the ordering is a little unclear.  Your sample data and code do not match.  The following assumes some combination of the date and orderid, but there may be other columns that better capture what you mean by "preceding" and "following".

This is a little tricky, because you don't want to always include the first and last rows -- unless necessary.  So, look at two columns:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(TimeSinceLast) over (partition by custid order by orderdate, orderid) as next_tsl,
             lag(TimeSinceLast) over (partition by custid order by orderdate, orderid) as prev_tsl,
             lead(orderid) over (partition by custid order by orderdate, orderid) as next_orderid,
             lag(orderid) over (partition by custid order by orderdate, orderid) as prev_orderid
      from t
     ) t
where TimeSinceLast is not null or
      (next_tsl is null and next_orderid is not null) or
      (prev_tsl is null and prev_orderid is not null);
```

Comment: The ordering is not clear from the question. If you look at the expected result your query won't produce it.

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . I think that is an issue of partitioning by the customer id.

Answer (score 0):

USE APPLY

```
DECLARE @TransTable TABLE (OrderID char(4), CustID char(3), OrderDate date, TimeSinceLast int)

INSERT @TransTable VALUES
('123a', 'A01', '06.20.2018', 20),
('123y', 'B05', '06.20.2018' ,31),
('113k', 'A01', '05.18.2018' ,NULL), ------- need this
('168x', 'C01', '04.17.2018' ,8),
('999y', 'B05', '04.15.2018' ,NULL), ------- need this
('188k', 'A01', '04.15.2018' ,123),
('678a', 'B05', '03.16.2018' ,45)

SELECT B.OrderID, B.CustID, B.OrderDate, B.TimeSinceLast 
FROM @TransTable A
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 0 AS rn, A.OrderID, A.CustID, A.OrderDate, A.TimeSinceLast
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 2 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN T.OrderDate > A.OrderDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(day, T.OrderDate, A.OrderDate))) rn, 
    T.OrderID, T.CustID, T.OrderDate, T.TimeSinceLast
    FROM @TransTable T 
    WHERE T.CustID = A.CustID AND T.OrderID <> A.OrderID
    ORDER BY rn
) B
WHERE A.TimeSinceLast IS NULL
ORDER BY B.CustID, B.OrderDate DESC
```